# I need help approaching this limit of limit.

Tags: calculus, limits

As i was trying to study today, I came across this limit that I have no idea how to solve.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} ( \lim_{x \to 0} (1+\sin^2(x)+\sin^2(2x)+\cdots+\sin^2(nx))^\frac{1}{n^3\cdot x^2})$$

My first thought was the squeeze theorem:

If:
$ 0 \le \sin^2(x) \le 1$

Then:
$ 1 \le 1+\sin^2(x)+\sin^2(2x)+\cdots+\sin^2(nx) \le n+1$. Raising it to the power of $\frac{1}{n^3\cdot x^2}$, then

$$\large 1 \le 1+\sin^2(x)+\sin^2(2x)+\cdots+\sin^2(nx) \le (n+1)^\frac{1}{n^3\cdot x^2}$$

But I got stuck solving the limit for $(n+1)^\frac{1}{n^3*x^2}$.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `$\sin x$` for $\sin x$

Comment: Try $0 \leq \sin^2(kx) \leq (kx)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly we find the inner limit:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^n\sin^2(kx)\right)^{\frac 1{n^3x^2}}
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\exp\left(\frac{\log\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^n\sin^2(kx)\right)}{n^3x^2}\right)\\[12pt]
&=\exp\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^n\sin^2(kx)\right)}{\sum_{k=1}^n\sin^2(kx)}\cdot\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\sin^2(kx)}{n^3x^2}\right)\\[12pt]
&=\exp\left(1\cdot\frac 1{n^3}\lim_{x\to 0}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin^2(kx)}{x^2}\right)
=\exp\left(\frac 1{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^n k^2\right)\\[12pt]
&=\boldsymbol{\exp\left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n^3}\right)}.
\end{align*}
The outer limit follows immediately:

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{x\to 0}\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^n\sin^2(kx)\right)^{\frac 1{n^3x^2}}=\color{blue}{\boldsymbol{\sqrt[3]{\mathrm e}}}
$$

Comment: Hello.Thanks for giving me more hints.But i can't really understand what the exp(...) means I dont think I've encountered something put like that.

Comment: Every power $A^B$, $A>0$ can be expressed as $\mathrm e^{B\cdot\log A}=\exp(B\cdot\log A)$ where $\mathrm e$ is Euler's number. The symbol $\exp$ is used for better readability,